# Sending Commands to and Receiving Data from Advantech ADAM-6024 through Python Socket Library

Tags: python, sockets, ascii, ethernet

I am trying to send commands to and receive data from Advantech's ADAM-6024 Ethernet-based Data Acquisition and Control Module using Python. I am using a MacBook Pro and am connected to the device through an ethernet connection.

Here is the manual for ADAM-6000 series devices:

http://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile4/1-1M99LTH/ADAM-6000_User_Manaul_Ed_9.pdf

I have written a python class called ADAMConnection which contains methods that set up a socket connection to the module and then send a command to it and asks for a response.

I can make the socket connection but have had no luck communicating with the device. Here is the library that I've written:

```
class ADAMConnection:
    def __init__(self, host, eth_port):
        self.host = host
        self.eth_port = eth_port
        self.adamsock = None

    ###############################################################################
    # ConnectADAM() method
    ###############################################################################
    def OpenADAMConnection( self ):
      self.adamsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      self.adamsock.settimeout(2)
      try:
         self.adamsock.connect((self.host,self.eth_port))
         #self.adamsock.send(str.encode("*RST\r\n")) #Example of what's done in DAQConn
         #TODO: Do we need any initialization commands?
         print("ADAM connected..")
         time.sleep(0.05)
         return True
      except socket.timeout:
         print('\n*************** ERROR *****************')
         print('Attempt to connect to the ADAM timed out. \n' + \
               'Make sure it\'s powered on and plugged in.')
         print('*************** ERROR *****************\n\n')
         return False
      except OSError:
         print('\n*************** ERROR *****************')
         print('Unable to connect to the ADAM. \n' + \
               'Make sure it\'s powered on and plugged in.')
         print('*************** ERROR *****************\n\n')
         return False

    def GetModuleName(self,commandString):
        #self.adamsock.send(str.encode("ASCII STRING")) 
        self.adamsock.send(str.encode(commandString,encoding="ascii")) 
        time.sleep(0.05)
        adam_out = self.adamsock.recv(100) #is the 100 needed?  Maybe try for now
        time.sleep(0.05)
        return adam_out
```

When I import this library and try to make a socket connection, I am successful. I am trying to talk to it through ASCII commands, so I use port 502. I knew to use this port from this link:

http://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile1/GF-1HBO9/Which%20TCP%20and%20UDP%20Ports%20do%20ADAM%20Ethernet%20Modules%20Use.pdf

However, when I attempt to ask the ADAM-6024 module for its module name, I get meaningless output that I don't understand. I first attempted to send a command to read the module name using the ASCII syntax I found on pages 112 of the manual (first link), but received what appears to be garbage output. To confirm this, I sent a command that I knew was meaningless to the module and received a similar output.

Below is the python code I used to do what I describe above:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ADAMConnection
>>> module1 = ADAMConnection.ADAMConnection("192.168.6.70",502)
>>> module1.OpenADAMConnection()
ADAM connected..
True
>>> module1.GetModuleName("01M0Dh")
b'01M0\x00\x03\x00\x80\x01'
>>> module1.GetModuleName("nonsense")
b'nons\x00\x03s\xe5\x01'
```

I am barely proficient with Python and do not know anything about Modbus/TCP/ASCII/Socket connections, so I do not know if I am missing something incredibly obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That you succeeded in sending and receiving data is a good start. However, I don't know how you got the command string `"01M0Dh"`. This [User Manual](https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile4/1-242CMGX/ADAM-6000_User_Manaul_Ed.11-D5.pdf), section *7.4 ASCII Commands for ADAM-6000 Modules* says:

> ###### $aaM
>
> **Name** Read module name
> **Description** Returns the name of a specific module
> **Syntax** $aaM(cr)
>  $ is a delimiter
>  aa (range 00~FF) is the 2-character hex slave address of the specified module (always 01)
>  M refers to the read model number command
>  (cr) is the terminating character, carriage return (0Dh)

This corresponds to the Python string `"$01M\r"`.

Looking at the response data packets you posted and also according to the port 502, it appears that [Modbus TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Modbus_TCP_frame_format_(primarily_used_on_Ethernet_networks)) protocol is used. The manual is somewhat unclear about this, but it may be that the ASCII command is to be imbedded in a Modbus TCP frame; the string would then be like e. g. `"..\0\0\0\5$01M\r"`. I can't however rule out that the ASCII commands are meant to be sent by UDP to port 1025. If you don't succeed that way, you could also try with HTTP from a browser as described in section *D.2 REST Resources for ADAM*, e. g. `http://host/digitalinput/all/value`.

Comment: Thank you @Armali for this reply. I didn't know the '"0Dh"' translated to '"\r"' when writing a Python string. When I try '"$01M\r"' as you suggest I get a similar output of 'b'$01M\x00\x03\x00\x80\x01''', compared to '"b'$01M\x00\x03h\x80\x01'" when I enter '"$01M0Dh"'. It seems the difference is one of the middle hex characters being '03' instead of '03h' and an extra '00' hex character, which makes me wonder if there is a deeper problem here.

Comment: Indeed there seems to be a deeper problem, although all the shown responses are nine bytes long and there is no extra character - `\x03` `\x00` and `\x03` `h` are both two bytes. I added some thoughts to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this Armali. An Advantech technical support engineer informed me that ASCII strings can only be sent to 1025/UDP, while I am sending to 502/TCP. I am not sure why this is, but I tried it out and the Python socket library returned an OSError exception. Out of curiosity, I tried all of the port numbers on the list of ADAM-6000 ports and found only 502 (function:
TCP ASCII/Modbus comm.) and 5450 (function: Download) make successful connections. Not sure why this is.

Comment: I also tried with HTTP as you suggested (e.g. http://192.168.6.70/digitalinput/all/value) and only receive a blank window.

Comment: You could post the complete 1025/UDP _OSError exception_ message - perhaps this can be overcome. Otherwise, you could perhaps waive ASCII commands and try with pure Modbus protocol. As a last resort, if you have access to a machine running with the supplied software, you could capture traffic with Wireshark and see what format is used.

Comment: Thanks for.the suggestion Armali: I finally found the solution. When I create the socket object ("socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)") I am implicitly establishing that I want a TCP connection. Instead, I have the object expect a UDP protocol instead with "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)" and this solves it: It reads the model number back to me, and other commands are working as expected. I will write an answer to my question formally soon. Thank you for all of your help!